# proof by induction, how to start with the specific example. 5^n - 1 is divisible by 4

Tags: induction

I am looking at proof by induction as part of my maths module for my upcoming examination. I ave worked through several problems of induction, but i am not yet fully capable.

The problem i have been asked is:

for every n greater of equal to 1 show that:

```
5^n - 1 is divisible by 4.
```

Most of the examples i have been working through have have been things like:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ..... + (k+1) = 1+2+3+.....+ k + k+1
```

which i can then easily work through. I am struggling to define the opening to this problem so far i have:

```
5^k - 1 = ((5^k) - 1) + ((5^k+1) -1)
```

But then i am not sure where to progress in my calculation. Have i got completely the wrong idea here?

Hope somebody can help me.

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Step $k+1$:
$$5^{k+1}-1=5(5^k-1)+4$$

Comment: still not quite getting it :/ tried multiplying out the brackets, which left me with 25^k - 5 + 4 = 25^k - 9 but i don't think that's the way to go.

Comment: @chris You know, by induction, $\,5^k-1 = 4j.\,$ What happens when you substitute that above?

Comment: @chrisedwards By hypothesis of step $k$,  $4$ divides $5^k-1$ so it divides $5(5^k-1)+4$

Comment: @BillDubuque i end up with 5 x 4j + 4. since 4j is the step for k-1.

Comment: @Chris Is that divisible by $4$, as desired?

Comment: yes indeed, thanks. is there a "proper" way to format te answer or is that suffcient? should i simplify to 5x4j+4 20j+4?

Comment: @chris You could pull the factor of $4$ out and write it in the form  $4m,\,$ to make it obvious that it is divisible by $4$.

Comment: Thank you! it's quite easy once its been explained properly! still a bit confusing at times.

Comment: @chrisedwards: You should also check again what $5\cdot5^k$ simplifies to.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: We see it is short, but we see it is effective. :+)